# What's the proper way to implement formatting on v-model in Vue.js 2.0

Tags: vue.js

For a simple example: textbox to input currency data.
The requirement is to display user input in "$1,234,567" format and remove decimal point.

I have tried vue directive. directive's update method is not called when UI is refreshed due to other controls. so value in textbox reverts to the one without any formatting.

I also tried v-on:change event handler. But I don't know how to call a global function in event handler. It is not a good practice to create a currency convert method in every Vue object.

So what is the standard way of formatting in Vue 2.0 now?

Regards

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Please check this working jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/bgzhw68m/

In this example, the formatted currency input is a component in itself, that uses `v-model` just like any other form element in Vue.js. You can initialize this component as follows:

```html
<my-currency-input v-model="price"></my-currency-input>
```

`my-currency-input` is a self-contained component that formats the currency value when the input box is **inactive**. When user puts cursor inside, the formatting is removed so that user can modify the value comfortably.

Here is how it works:

The `my-currency-input` component has a computed value - `displayValue`, which has `get` and `set` methods defined. In the `get` method, if input box is not active, it returns formatted currency value.

When user types into the input box, the `set` method of `displayValue` computed property emits the value using `$emit`, thus notifying parent component about this change.

Reference for using `v-model` on custom components: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events

Comment: Much better! The whole idea of masking really bothers me but this works well.

Comment: @BillCriswell Thanks! Even I liked this better than my other example, as it is a fully self-contained component, and the parent template is clean.

Comment: I loved your approach so I expanded on it a bit:  https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/xxuda425/5/

Comment: Thanks @BillCriswell, your example looks very clean! I didn't know about toLocaleString, which handles the cases where dot is used for digit separator and comma for decimal. It is much better than using a copy-pasted regular expression, which I am yet to decode how it works. Also, specifying mask as a separate input is brilliant! This will allow other types of input formatting, like date formatter, non-dollar currency type, etc. Thanks for spending time on this, I will use your jsFiddle to build my general purpose reusable input component :)

Comment: Thanks. I did the same vue component implementation last night, and posted. but the post is disappeared.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks, I've adopted it for my souped-up input component. I had to add a slightly messy kludge to get it to work as I wanted for currency fields, namely to truncate or round the actual value to 2 decimal places (rather than just display it thus). I added a @change handler which calls toFixed(2) on the value. I'm wondering whether this could be handled more neatly in the unmask method, though? I couldn't find a way, I have to say.

Comment: One issue with doing `value.toFixed(2)` is that it becomes a string. You will have to remember to convert it back to a number afterwards, otherwise you will end up with results like `"2" + "2" = "22"`. I don't have any clean solution to control the precision, I can see that it will get messy. But it should be fine as long as the mess stays within the component, which can be taken as a black-box and reused everywhere.

Comment: Good point. I'm now using parseFloat after toFixed, which resolves the issue.

Comment: Why not use international format https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat?

Comment: Nice usefull and small. Thanks!

Comment: Good but will need to think of a way to add type="number" in... as this has to be removed for the currency to be displayed inside input

Comment: @Mani Thanks so much for your solution! I am not good with regex and I need this to work for a number in cents and then emitted in cents. Meaning I could type $7.99 and it would emit 799. Can anyone help me with a solution for that?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/w6oo9b6j/

It works by modifying the input string (your currency value) during the focus-out and focus-in events, as follows:

```html
<input type="text" v-model="formattedCurrencyValue" @blur="focusOut" @focus="focusIn"/>
```

1. When you put the cursor inside the input box, it takes `this.currencyValue` and converts it to plain format, so that user can modify it.
2. After the user types the value and clicks elsewhere (focus out), `this.currencyValue` is recalculated after ignoring non-numeric characters, and the display text is formatted as required.

The currency formatter (reg exp) is a copy-paste from here: [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

If you do not want the decimal point as you mentioned in question, you can do `this.currencyValue.toFixed(0)` in the `focusOut` method.

Comment: This is the only sane, not annoying approach I've seen to input masks.

Comment: Thanks, I want to have a solution that is closer to Vue architecture. I have tried to use computed property (ugly solution, I have to add a computed property for each currency input). Now when user types in "1111" (string), model value is 1111 (number). Then user enters ".22" after "1111", setter removes decimal point. But input textbox is 1111.22 since model value is still 1111 and getter won't be invoked.

Comment: I have added another answer to this question. As it involved a complete rewrite of the jsFiddle example, I decided to add a separate answer instead of editing this one. Please see if it meets your requirements. I use a computed property just like you specified. The decimals are handled internally, while the display shows only whatever precision you specify in `toFixed()` while formatting currency.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a component. According to Mani's answer, it should use $emit.

```
Vue.component('currency', {
template: '<input type="text"' +
            ' class="form-control"' +
            ' :placeholder="placeholder""' +
            ' :title="title"' +
            ' v-model="formatted" />',
props: ['placeholder', 'title', 'value'],
computed: {
    formatted: {
        get: function () {
            var value = this.value;
            var formatted = currencyFilter(value, "", 0);
            return formatted;
        },
        set: function (newValue) {
            var cleanValue = newValue.replace(",", "");
            var intValue = parseInt(cleanValue, 10);
            this.value = 0;
            this.value = intValue;
        }
    }
}
}
```

);

Answer (score 1):

Using Vue custom directives + .toLocaleString() is also a very good option.

```
Vue.directive("currency", {
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    el.value = binding.value && Number(binding.value).toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: !binding.arg ? 'USD' : binding.arg });
    el.onblur = function(e) {
      e.target.value = Number(e.target.value).toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: !binding.arg ? 'USD' : binding.arg});
    };
    el.onfocus = function(e) {
      e.target.value =
        e.target.value && Number(e.target.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ""));
    };
    el.oninput = function(e) {
      vnode.context.$data[binding.expression] = e.target.value;
    };
  }
});
```

Here is the example link: https://codepen.io/Mahmoud-Zakaria/pen/YzPvNmO